# SQL hexadecimal string comparison

Tags: sql, string

**Background:**

I have a sql DB for my ID numbers. They look like "44b1e3d6e8ee4da7" and up to this point I have been able to detect them based off of a difference query.

**query:**

```
use [table]
select date,id
from View
 with(nolock) where id like '________________'
 and DIFFERENCE(substring(id,charindex('?____=', id)+6,  
 (len(id) - (charindex('?____=', id) +5)) ), 'ae93ed317663c028') > 0
```

but now the data has somewhat changed and people are putting in id's like this "251&r=1328129429".

How do I tell the difference between "44b1e3d6e8ee4da7" and "251&r=1328129429" easily and quickly? I know they are both 16 characters long. I know that the second string has a & and a =, however I don't wish to use an extra AND !CONTAINS "& or =" unless I have to.

any suggestions?

**update to question:**

as @gbn stated my original question was not answered. This is because it was only a partial question. I did not know at the time fully what I was asking. My question has morphed into "how do I remove from my result pool strings that have special characters in them and leave only the 16 digit hexadecimal strings.

@MartinSmith has provided an excellent code example that answers that question. Thank you @MartinSmith for looking through my question to what the real question was and answering it. It shows a great deal of linear thinking and I applaud your effort and answer. Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `valueA <> valueB`? ID numbers match or they don't... not much in between...

Comment: i have to pull reports for new ID's entered. I know they are all 16 characters long and a hexadecimal format with no special characters in it.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "a simple valueA <> valueB"?

Comment: yes, but you can still just compare them normally. You asked `How do i tell the difference between "44b1e3d6e8ee4da7" and "251&r=1328129429"`. Easy. `"44b1e3d6e8ee4da7" <> "251&r=1328129429"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find strings that are "16 characters long and a hexadecimal format" you can use

```
WHERE id LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]',16)
```

Comment: Bad question. You haven't answered "How do i tell the difference between "44b1e3d6e8ee4da7" and "251&r=1328129429" easily and quickly? "...

Comment: can you modify that to look at the last 16 characters of a string like this "imps.php?sgms=248&r=1328084992"? i think i might have found a second usage for your method :)

Comment: @toosweetnitemare - Use `LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('[0-9A-Fa-f]',16)` to find strings ending in that.